# Execute a Jupyter notebook with papermill and output a unique filename

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, papermill

I'd like to use `papermill` as part of a **data science workflow** to record experiments. The key idea is that the output notebook should be stored as a unique artifact -- an immutable record of the experiment. As such, I want the output filename to be **a unique filename**, such as `experiment_<hash>.ipynb`. How can I do this automatically at the linux CLI? From the papermill docs, it looks like I must specify the exact output filename like

```
papermill local/input.ipynb s3://bkt/output.ipynb -f parameters.yaml
```

whereas what I really want is something like

```sh
papermill local/input.ipynb s3://bkt/output_[UNIQUE HASH HERE].ipynb -f parameters.yaml
```

I want to do this within the `papermill` call **automatically**. A manual way would be

```sh
$ echo cat input.ipynb | md5sum
22f69c25ee3a855b17fead21e702668a
$ papermill local/input.ipynb s3://bkt/output_22f69c25ee3a855b17fead21e702668a.ipynb -f parameters.yaml
```

but I don't want to do it manually with cut and paste.

Comment: I can get a datetime which is probably good enough with... `papermill input.ipynb s3://bkt/output_$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").ipynb`

Comment: Appending the current date and time like you have done is what I usually do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command substitution, for example like this:

```
papermill local/input.ipynb s3://bkt/output_`date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32`.ipynb -f parameters.yaml
```

or newer way

```
papermill local/input.ipynb s3://bkt/output_$(date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32).ipynb -f parameters.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a Python script and generate the unique ID:

```py
# run_experiment.py
import uuid
import papermill as pm

experiment_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

pm.execute_notebook('input.ipynb', f'{experiment_id}.ipynb')
```

Then run it:

```bash
python run_experiment.py
```